# How to simulate Hall sensor output on clutch to enable remote-start of vehicle?

Tags: sensor

I love tinkering with electronics but never been good at the math so didn't take it any further growing up.

So basically I want to install a remote start on my van and need to temporally disable/trick the PCM to thinking I have depressed the clutch. (I know what you are going to say....that's dangerous.) But my remote starter has other built in safety devices like neutral detection to stop it being started when in gear. Unfortunately I have a hall sensor on my clutch system which senses the exact position of the clutch, it has 4 wires.

The wires are as follows:

1. Cpp1- which is clutch pos top.
2. cpp2- clutch pos bottom.
3. Signal wire which I believe is ground to pcm
4. Vref voltage

I noticed when my foot is NOT depressing the clutch I have like 0.8 V and when fully depressed it's around 4 V. Edit: from wires cpp2 and signal return.

How do I simulate the fully depressed action? Remember it's only temp, the remote starter initiates the trigger only on crank via a negative feed.

---

I'm using a Fortin all in one remote starter and bypass module. I've wired it mostly in via the gateway can/bus connections of the van. The clutch bypass wire from the R-starter grounds to a simple on off switch temporarily to bypass the clutch but obviously this setup won't work for the hall sensor. I think I can work it so I have a positive signal wire from the RS to the hall sensor if needed? I wondered if I could just use the 5v reference voltage wire to enable it but haven't tried it yet, thought I would speak to someone who knows more before I kill something.

[image: clutch sensor schematics from wiring manual, i cant find any details of the switch itself but i know the vref is 5v]

Basically which wire do I need to alter to achieve the trigger voltage which I'm guessing is from 2.6v-4.8v on the cpp2 control wire ??
Do I need to add a resistor in there somewhere to bring the voltage down on the VREF (I have no idea really, this is what I've heard others doing but not sure it applies to my setup )
Or can I just link the VREF voltage straight to the cpp2 wire to give 5v??
Please help asap as this is the last step to completing the system. Thanks in advance.
Chris

Comment: what are you using for remote controller and how're you wiring it to your van's ECU ? Simulating 0.8VDC to 4VDC should be straight forward.

Comment: Please see update to the question.

Comment: @Chrisc - Hi, I have moved your new details into an edit i.e. an update to the question. That is how details which could be generally useful to other people, should be added on Stack Exchange. Since you asked the question, you are unlikely to have a valid use for the text entry box below labeled "Your Answer" - unless you find the *full & final* solution to your own problem, which is different from any other answer which is given. Please check the [tour] & [help] to see more about the site rules and the Q&A approach here, which differs from typical forums. Thanks.

Comment: Any ideas anyone?? Left me hanging with "should be simple enough" then nothing lol.